# Does Angular have a let-name directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cdk

In [this article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cdk-portals-b02f66dd020c) the author uses a `let-name` directive on the template like this:

```
<ng-template #testTemplate let-name>
   <div>User {{ name }} </div>        
</ng-template>`
```

Is that part of `angular/core` or `angular/cdk` directives or something the author invented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax)

> The Angular microsyntax lets you configure a directive in a compact,
> friendly string. The microsyntax parser translates that string into
> attributes on the `<ng-template>`

For example, microsyntax in Angular allows you to write

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</div>
```

instead of

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items"><div>{{item}}</div></ng-template>.
```